# Are objects cleaned up when references to them are nulled?

Tags: java

```
public class App1 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
   Point point_1 = new Point(5,5);
   Point point_2 = new Point(7,8);
   Circle circle_1 = new Circle(point_2, 10);
   point_1 = null;
   point_2 = null;
 }
}
```

How many object references exist after this code has executed? Why?

Answer (score 7):

After this code has executed, exactly none, since it will have exited :-)

If you mean at the point just before exit, there's a reference on the stack to your circle and a reference in your circle to the second point, assuming the constructor stores it.

Comment: Minor point: The compiler might not bother to put circle_1 on the stack since it is an unused local.....

Answer (score 7):

Despite formulation problems, the snippet is actually quite instructive on certain aspects of garbage collectibility. Let's take a look at it line-by-line.

```
 Point point_1 = new Point(5,5);
```

So we've declared a reference variable `point_1`, and it points to a `new Point`. Let's assume for now that the constructor of `Point` doesn't do anything fancy and simply set fields `final int x, y` with the given values.

Thus, we now have something like this:

[image]

Now let's take a look at the next line:

```
Point point_2 = new Point(7,8);
```

Now we have something like this:

[image]

Now let's take a look at the next line:

```
Circle circle_1 = new Circle(point_2, 10);
```

Here again we don't quite know how `Circle` is implemented, but it's reasonable to assume that it has a `final Point center` and `final int radius` fields, and with the `Point center` specifically, it simply sets the reference to the given `Point` (i.e. no defensive copying since `Point` is immutable).

So now we may have something like this:

[image]

Then with the next two statements, we set `point_1` and `point_2` to point to `null` respectively:

```
point_1 = null;
point_2 = null;
```

So now we have something like this:

[image]

We can now observe that:

- The object `[aPoint(5 5)]` is no longer reachable
- The object `[aPoint(7 8)]`, though no longer refered to by `point_2`, is still refered to by `[aCircle(10)].center`.

Garbage collectibility is defined by whether or not an object is reachable by a live reference. The object `[aPoint(5 5)]`, we can strongly assume (based on how we think `Point` is implemented), is no longer reachable, so it is eligible for collection (it's a garbage! No one can "pick it up" now!).

On the other hand, the object `[aPoint(7, 8)]` is still referred to by `[aCircle(10)].center`, so we can say that it's *NOT* eligible for collection (it's not a garbage! Someone is still "hanging on" to it!).

---

#### Moral

So no, definitely setting a reference to `null` does *NOT* make the object previously being referred to automatically eligible for collection. It depends on the object itself, whether or not there are any references to the object.

Certainly, though, setting a reference to `null` *CAN* help make an object be eligible for collection, e.g. when that reference is the last remaining to the object.

You do *NOT* however, have to *ALWAYS* set a reference to `null` to make garbage collection "works". When variables goes out of scope, the reference is no longer alive, so in those kinds of cases explicitly setting to `null` is simply redundant code.

The classic example when explicitly setting to `null` *DOES* work is the `Stack` example: when the top element is popped from the `Stack`, the `Stack` should no longer refer to the object from its internal data structure.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 6: Eliminate obsolete object references*

#### Related questions

- [Does variable = null set it for garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931170/does-variable-null-set-it-for-garbage-collection)

Comment: @paxdiablo: yuml.me ; see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55442/web-apps-to-make-your-answers-awesomer

Comment: Wow, your answers keep getting cooler, keep it up! You'll be giving Jon Skeet a run for his money soon enough. :P

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

1. Define what you mean for an object reference to "exist".
2. It is impossible to know how many object references were even created, without details of the `Point` and `Circle` classes.
3. The answer is irrelevant, because after the `main` method exits none of the objects will be reachable ... whether or not the references still "exist".

We might infer that at the point in time immediately before the `main` method returns there will be one reachable reference to a `Circle` object and one reachable reference to a `Point`.  But one has to make some (reasonable) assumptions about how those two classes are implemented to make that inference.  (For example, one has to assume that the respective constructors don't add the `Point` and `Circle` reference to some static data structure.)

> Are objects cleaned up when references to them are nulled?

No.  Objects are cleaned up when the garbage collector runs, and it determines that the objects in question are no longer reachable.  In this sense, "reachable" means that you can get to the object by following a chain of references to the object starting from:

- a static attribute of some class
- a local variable of some method that is currently being executed by some thread
- an attribute of some other reachable object, or
- an element of some other reachable array.

(I've simplified the explanations of GC and reachability a bit to avoid confusing the OP with things he/she won't understand yet.)