# Garbage collection of null object returned from RMI methods

Tags: java, garbage-collection, rmi

I have a RMI method that returns an object to the client. When the method is completed, another RMI call for garbage collector is made implicitly. If I return null object, would the GC still be called? I cannot find any text confirming this anywhere. 
related: [Does variable = null set it for garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931170/does-variable-null-set-it-for-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a null object. There is a null *reference.* In the case you mention there is nothing to garbage-collect.

> When the method is completed, another RMI call for garbage collector is made implicitly.

I don't know what you mean by this. If you're referring to DGC, it doesn't work like that. If not, you're mistaken.

Comment: I'm intercepting RMI calls and I get these calls: `sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl_Stub[0:0:0, 2]: java.rmi.dgc.Lease dirty(java.rmi.server.ObjID[], long, java.rmi.dgc.Lease)`
Which I assume is DGC, as you mentioned. What exactly is this? Please help me understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, is it possible to avoid this call? Currently from my RMI method, I return: `return (new reponse_obj(1,true,null)`. Would creating a local object and returning it solve this?

Comment: DGC is *distributed* garbage-collection, defined in the [RMI Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch4.html). I don't understand your last question. You'll have to post some code. In your question.