# Is it worth setting objects to null after their use is completed?

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a 2d game in javafx. There are certain elements that I remove from scene once they have done their part. Do you think its a good practice to set all variables and values to `0/null` in those objects just as they are removed?

I do know that such a level of optimization may not be required given modern computers have GBs of memory. But I am trying to kind of get as much lower memory as I can (just a personal challenge). I wonder if GC can detect that these objects have completed their lifecycle and are no longer required....?

Comment: it´s better to set the references to these objects to null / remove them from collections, instead of nulling all the variables. The gc will automaticly detect that theyr lifecycle is over by then because theres no references to that object anymore

Comment: I would argue it's better to ensure, wherever possible, that the variables go out of scope, rather than setting them to null. Setting a reference to null will make no difference to gc if there are still other references to the same object elsewhere anyway.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931170/does-variable-null-set-it-for-garbage-collection

Comment: @KevinEsche yes, I am removing those objects from collection and then setting the references to those objects to null. For all primitives, I set them to their initial value (0, false etc). For Images and ImageViews I set them to null too (first the Image associated with ImageView and then the ImageView). So I suppose I am doing this right?

James_D I have class variables, so being fairly new to java, I do not really have an idea of how to make class variables go out of scope (if there is one; which I doubt but just making sure). So I suppose setting references to null is ok in this case?

Comment: I would avoid making them "class variables" (I assume you mean instance variables) in the first place, if possible. At any rate, the standard recommendation is to minimize the scope of your variables.

Answer (score 3):

From the Book ["Effective Java"](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=6):

> Nulling out references should be the exception, not the norm. The best way to eliminate an obsolete reference is to let the variable that contained the reference fall out of scope.

Comment: In which the author says (his emphasis) **"Nulling out references should be the exception, not the norm.** The best way to eliminate an obsolete reference is to let the variable that contained the reference fall out of scope. "