# In terms of memory, what happens to a null variable in Kotlin?

Tags: variables, kotlin, garbage-collection, garbage

When I first learned to code, I was told "When you declare a variable, you RESERVE space in memory for that variable," but if the variable is nullable in Kotlin, when is the variable converted to null to liberate its space?

For example, I have a nullable String variable.

```kotlin
var x: String? = "Some text"
```

When I set `x` to `null`, is the space in memory liberated?

```kotlin
x = null
```

I read about variables in Kotlin's page, but it does not mention anything about this:

- [Declaring variables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/declaring-variables.html)
- [Null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/null-safety.html)

I understand [from other reading](https://deepu.tech/memory-management-in-jvm/) that if I don't have any reference to this variable, then the GC will liberate the memory, but I have a variable with a `null` value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does variable = null set it for garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931170/does-variable-null-set-it-for-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 4):

A variable for an object always takes up 4 bytes or 8 bytes (depending on whether the VM is 32 bit or 64 bit), whether it is set to null or anything else. A variable for a primitive takes up as much as that primitive is defined for (4 bytes for floats and ints, 8 bytes for doubles and longs, etc.).

So the declaration of a String reserves 4 bytes. That memory is reclaimed when the variable goes out of scope. If it's declared inside a function, it goes out of scope when the function returns. If it's declared as a property *with a backing field*, it goes out of scope when the class instance it is part of is reclaimed by the garbage collector. (Note that a property might not have a backing field at all and therefore not need to reserve space per instance for the property.) If it's declared in an `object` or at the top level space, it will never go out of scope while the application is running.

Don't confuse the variable itself with the objects it can point to. These will take up a lot more than 4 bytes, and will of course vary in size. Their memory is reserved when they are instantiated and reclaimed by the garbage collector when they are no longer referenced anywhere (so if you set the last reference to an ojbect to `null`, that *does* cause its memory to be freed).

Comment: "If it's declared as a property, it goes out of scope when the class instance it is part of is reclaimed by the garbage collector. (Note that a property might not have a backing field at all.)" I think it may not be clear enough that memory is reserved only if there is a backing field.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, thanks. I tried to clarify it a bit.

Comment: so, if the variable has an value grow in space, but if is nullify its reduced, and grow again if set another value?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. But to reiterate, a variable is not the object itself. It is a number pointing at a memory address, so it always takes up the same amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate concepts involved here.

The first is the idea of a variable.  As @Tenfour04 explains, all object variables require 4 or 8 bytes (32 or 64 bit JVM).  This space is used to store a *reference* to an object.

The second is the object itself.  In your example, you instantiate an instance of the String class with "Some text".  The object will contain an array of `char` primitives that are the individual characters in the string ('S', 'o', 'm', etc.)  When the String is instantiated, space in the heap will be allocated by the JVM.

While your variable contains a reference to the "Some text" String object, the GC will take no action.  When your application code no longer has any references to the object, it becomes eligible for garbage collection (although nothing defines exactly when this will happen).

Again, in your example, when you set the variable `x` to be `null` you are removing the reference and the "Some text" object will become eligible for collection.

Normally, it is not necessary to explicitly null a reference, the GC is very good at finding objects that are no longer referenced.  Rather than using an explicit null assignment, it is better to look at the scope of the variable.  Once a variable goes out of scope, it is no longer in use and therefore the reference it has to an object is no longer in use.  Scope could be a function/method or a block of code, etc.